# My code keeps looping, when it should not

Tags: python

I'm creating a python program that given any angles/sides of a triangle will solve for all other applicable sides. to do this I have a dictionary of lists with lengths a,b,c and sides aa,ba,ca. the dictionary is structured so the first item in the list is the value of the key and the second item is a 0 or a 1, depending on if it is answered or not.

The program takes the second value of the list and puts it into another dictionary i called `eqdict`. for eqdict the value is either a 1 or a 0, depending if the value is known or not. With this we can do Pythagorean theorem, so if a+b+c=2, then we know 1 value is missing so it starts a function to find the missing side. After this function the answer gets saved with the `saveanswer` function, and the equation finder function is called again. However when the program goes back through equation finder, the `eqdict` for whichever character it found is not set to 0, so it has a continuous loop.

```
import math

def main():
    #creating terms in strings because I cant find an answer on how
    #to make floats with a non zero no value

    global terms
    terms={"a":[0,0],"b":[0,0],"c":[0,0],"aa":[0,0],"ba":[0,0],"ca":[0,0]}

    selectterms()

def selectterms():
    """takes user input for terms"""

    doneterm=False
        
    while not doneterm:
        print("Please select the variable and then write it's value")
        print("When done, please press enter with command prompt empty")
        term1=input("Variable: ")
        
        
        #to start program need to enter no command
        if term1=="":
            doneterm=True
            appender()
            
        #to end program after its finished
        if doneterm ==False:
            term2=float(input("Number: "))
            terms[term1]=[term2]
            terms[term1].append(1)
    return

def addtoeqdict(term):
  eqdict[term]=1
  return

def saveanswer(term,num):
  """saves answer to answers dict, makes second term 1 and sends back the number"""
  answers={}
  print("saveanswer")
  answers[term]=num
  #print("answers",answers)
  terms[term][1]=1
  terms[term][0]=num
  eqdict[term]=1
  print(answers)
  print(eqdict)
  eqfinder(**eqdict)

def appender():
    """Append a 0 on to terms that have only 1 item in list"""

    global eqdict

    eqdict={}

    keys=terms.keys()

    for i in keys:
      i = str(i)
      eqdict[i]=int(terms[i][1])

    eqfinder(**eqdict)
    return

def eqfinder(a,b,c,aa,ba,ca):
    """runs through given terms to find any possible equations.
    looks for possible equations by adding appended values"""

    nomoreterms=False

    while nomoreterms == False:
      print(terms)
      if terms["aa"][0]!=0 or terms["ba"][0]!=0 or terms["ca"][0]!=0:
        if terms["aa"][0]<0 or terms["ba"][0]<0 or terms["ca"][0]<0:
          posangles(terms["aa"][0],terms["ba"][0],terms["ca"][0])
      print(a,b,c,aa,ba,ca)
      if c+a+b==2:
        cab(terms["c"][0],terms["a"][0],terms["b"][0])

      else:
        nomoreterms=True

def posangles(aa,ba,ca):
  print("Posangles")
  if aa<0:
    aa=aa*(-1)
    saveanswer("aa",aa)
  elif ba<0:
    ba=ba*(-1)
    saveanswer("ba",ba)
  elif ca<0:
    ca=ca*(-1)
    saveanswer("ca",ca)

def cab(c,a,b):
  print("cab")
  if c==0:
    c=math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
    saveanswer("c",c)
  elif a==0:
    a=math.sqrt(c**2-b**2)
    saveanswer("a", a)
  elif b==0:
    b=math.sqrt(c**2-a**2)
    saveanswer("b",b)

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] in the body of the question, not as an external link. This will make it easier to attract answers and help

Comment: Don't describe your code. Actually share your code. It's like you are asking a doctor to operate on your heart, but instead of going there in person to be operated on, you've just described your heart using words. We cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is your eqfinder function. You pass in `a, b, c` find the missing value using cab, and save the answer. It then gets back to eqfinder and checks `if a + b + c == 2` which it does since you never updated the `a, b, c` variables. There are number of fixes you could do to make this break out of the for loop. Here's one (added line marked with >>>):

```
def eqfinder(a,b,c,aa,ba,ca):
    """runs through given terms to find any possible equations.
    looks for possible equations by adding appended values"""

    nomoreterms=False

    while nomoreterms == False:
      print(terms)
      if terms["aa"][0]!=0 or terms["ba"][0]!=0 or terms["ca"][0]!=0:
        if terms["aa"][0]<0 or terms["ba"][0]<0 or terms["ca"][0]<0:
          posangles(terms["aa"][0],terms["ba"][0],terms["ca"][0])
      print(a,b,c,aa,ba,ca)
      if c+a+b==2:
        cab(terms["c"][0],terms["a"][0],terms["b"][0])
        >>> c, a, b = terms["c"][1],terms["a"][1],terms["b"][1]

      else:
        nomoreterms=True
```